# How can I reverse a bitwise operation to mark check boxes after page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a php function that has an array of all of these interest selections for users to choose from. I populate that data like so in a table:

```
foreach($interests as $key=>$value){
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="targetInterests" id="targetInterests"  value="<?php echo $key;?>" class="addeditplacefields">
<?php echo $value;?>
<?php   
}
?>
```

I am grabbing the values of the checked checkboxes as 1 for true and -1 for false, creating an array of the 1's and -1 and using a bitshift to store the values of those checked checkboxes in our mysql db like so:

```
var chkStr = "";
$(":checkbox").each(function(){
    chkStr += this.checked ? "1," : "-1,";
});
var chkStr = chkStr.substr(0, chkStr.length - 1);
// Turn checkbox string into an iterable array
var target =  JSON.parse("[" + chkStr + "]");

x = 0;
for (i=0; i<46; i++){
    var val = target[i];
    if (val == 1){
        x |= (1 << i);
    }
return x;
```

Bitwise operations are a new concept for me and I am struggling to find a neat solution that will repopulate those checked boxes after a user hits save and the page refreshes or when a user returns to the page to see what they have checked. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to store check box settings bit-wise is to use integers, where each checkbox would represent 1 bit of the integer. For example, if the check boxes were set:

```
checkbox 0 checked
checkbox 1 unchecked
checkbox 2 checked
```

This would represent 5 (1*2^0 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^2). In each term of the expression, the coefficient is either 1 or 0 depending on whether the checkbox was checked or unchecked, and the exponent is the index of the checkbox.

To decode, i.e. to test whether checkbox N was checked or uncheked, use the && (AND) operator, like so:

isCheckBoxNChecked = I && (2 ^ N)

where I is the integer value computed above.  If the result is 1 then the checkbox was checked, otherwise it was unchecked.  For example, to decode the checkbox settings from the example above:

```
for checkbox 0:  5 && (2 ^ 0) =1 (so checkbox 0 was checked)
for checkbox 1:  5 && (2 ^ 1) =0 (so checkbox 1 was unchecked)
for checkbox 2:  5 && (2 ^ 2) =1 (so checkbox 2 was checked)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, you definitely helped steer me in the right direction. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the advice of @mti2935 I realized that mapping the values using bitwise and js you are limited to 32 bits. I had 44 elements I was trying to change so once it reached the 32nd element it would start over. Not a happy result! So I went about solving it with an exponential function much like @mti2935 suggested the results are as follows:

```
var chkStr = "";

$(":checkbox").each(function(){
    chkStr += this.checked ? "1," : "-1,";
});
var chkStr = chkStr.substr(0, chkStr.length - 1);
// Turn checkbox string into an iterable array
var target =  JSON.parse("[" + chkStr + "]");

// Looking for values of 1 in the array
var hasCheck = $.inArray(1, target);
if (hasCheck != -1) {
    // loop through the values of the above array and work the bitwise magic
    y = 0;

    for (i=0; i<target.length; i++){
        var val = target[i];

        if (val === 1){
            y += Math.pow(2, i);
        }

    return y;
```

This value is written to a column in our DB and when we want to revisit the page and see what values were checked, or after posting the data on the page refresh, we can repopulate the state of the checkboxes like so:

```
rawInterests = getRawInterests();
var interestArray = JSON.parse("[" + rawInterests + "]");

$.each (interestArray, function (index, val) {
    if (val === 1){
        $("#targetInterests[value='" + index + "']").prop('checked', true);
    }   
});
```

Hope this can help someone else down the line.